semantic-release trims commit messages in changelog
Problem: Semantic release trims the commit messages in changelog. I.e.
1.0.0-rc.1 (2024-11-25)

Bug Fixes

JIRA-123: adding 1+1 does not give.... (86d6b4b)

Original commit is something like: fix(JIRA-123): adding 1+1 does not give 2 but instead it gives some random number between x and z
Aim: Display full commit message in changelog.
.releaserc.yml:
extends:
  - "@semantic-release/gitlab"
plugins:
  - - "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
    - preset: angular
  - "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
  - - "@semantic-release/exec"
    - verifyReleaseCmd: "echo '__version__ = \"${nextRelease.version}\"' > src/__version__.py"
  - "@semantic-release/gitlab"
  - - "@semantic-release/changelog"
    - changelogFile: CHANGELOG.md
  - - "@semantic-release/git"
    - assets:
        - src/__version__.py
        - CHANGELOG.md
branches:
  - "main"
  - name: "dev"
    prerelease: "rc"
ci: true


